# Prove or disprove: The Cauchy-product of serieses $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}$ converges to $e^{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, cauchy-product

Prove or disprove: The Cauchy-product of serieses $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}$ converges to $e^{2}$.

I'm not really sure if it's done like that but I have started by multiplying both serieses with each other, then use ratio test on the product:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k!}\cdot \frac{2^{k}}{k!} \right )$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left|\left(\frac{\frac{2^{k+1}}{(k+1)!\cdot (k+1)!}}{\frac{2^{k}}{k!\cdot k!}} \right)\right |=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left|\left(\frac{2^{k+1}\cdot k!\cdot k!}{(k+1)!\cdot (k+1)! \cdot 2^{k}}\right)\right |$$

$$= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left|\left(\frac{2^{k}\cdot 2 \cdot k! \cdot k!}{k!\cdot (k+1)\cdot k!\cdot (k+1)\cdot 2^{k}}\right)\right |= \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2}{(k+1)^{2}}\right)= 0$$

Thus the statement is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making a mistake from the beginning, the termwise product is **not** the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).
You should be looking at
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k
$$
with $$c_k = \sum_{\ell=0}^k a_\ell b_{k-\ell}.$$

In your case, this will lead to 
$$c_k = \sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{1}{(k-\ell)!}\frac{2^{\ell}}{\ell!} = 
\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{k!}{(k-\ell)!\ell!}{2^{\ell}} = \frac{(1+2)^k}{k!} = \frac{3^k}{k!}$$
and the (Cauchy) product will then be
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{3^k}{k!} = \cdots
$$

Comment: Note that this will be consistent with the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = e = e^1$, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!} = e^2$, and $e^a\cdot e^b = e^{a+b}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have read much about it today and now I understand your solution 100% :)

Comment: Depending on your definition of $e^x$ or the theorems you know about it, this may be immediate or "highly nontrivial." Can you assume the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x$? If not, what is the definition of $\exp$ you are using?

Comment: (A "cheap" way to show it differs from $e^2$, otherwise, it to observe that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{3^k}{k!} > \sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{3^k}{k!}$ (as all terms are positive); but $\sum_{k=0}^{3} \frac{3^k}{k!}=13$ (manual computation, we only have 4 terms to sum), while $e^2 < 3^2=9$ as $e\simeq 2.7 < 3$.)

Comment: I'm allowed to use that because we had it in our readings. Only thing is I somehow have to keep these important series in mind for the exam :P
and there is a lot I need to keep in mind >.<

Comment: Indeed... $e^x$ is a good one to remember, though -- it pops up *very* often.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_1(x) = \sum_k {1 \over k!} x^k = e^x$. 
Similarly, let $f_2(x) = \sum_k {1 \over k!} (2x)^k = e^{2x}$.

Let $f_3(x) = f_1(x) f_2(x) = e^{3x}$, then the power series coefficients of $f_3$
are given by the Cauchy product of the power series coefficients of $f_1,f_2$
and so the Cauchy product is given by $f_3(1) = e^3$.